# Unable to mount FAT32 drive on macOS: com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount, ntfs, fat32

I have a USB drive that I formatted on a Windows system. I want to read the data on my Mac, which is using macOS 12 Monterey.

However, the drive does not mount when I plug it in. Using Disk Utility to attempt to mount the grayed-out disk gives the error:

[image: com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868]

> Could not mount “disk4s2”. (`com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter` error `-119930868`.)

I had a similar issue with this drive formatted as NTFS, not sure if it was the same error. So I went back to windows and switched to FAT32, expecting that to work. But it doesn't. What's wrong? How can I mount this USB drive and read the data?

Comment: Try formatting the drive as FAT32 using the Mac. See if Windows can read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back and reformatted the disk via Disk Utility on my Mac.

The `MS-DOS (FAT32)` disk formatted via Disk Utility was readable on macOS, and also worked when I plugged it into the Windows machine.

This solved my immediate problem but I'm still not sure why the Windows-formatted disk won't mount on macOS.

[image: Disk Utility MS-DOS (FAT32)]